# How to handle case sensitive import collisions

Tags: go

I am using a third party library in GoLang that has previously had import paths in different case. Initially a letter was lower case then the author changed it to uppercase.

Some plugin authors updated their libraries and others didn't. In the meantime the original library author reverted the case change.

Now I find myself in a state where my application won't build due to to case import collisions.

How can one go about fixing this?

Many thanks

Comment: Edit your source files to match the current state of things? That's what I've always done. Curious to see if there's a better answer.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You could **vendor the dependencies**, and then go into the `vendor/` directory and **manually change** (try `grep`ing or `sed`ing the dependency), the dependencies.

For an introduction to vendoring, try here, https://blog.gopheracademy.com/advent-2015/vendor-folder/

The original repo can still live in your `GOPATH`, but the 'corrected' version can go in the vendor folder, in which the compiler will look *first* when linking dependencies.

There are many tools for vendoring, I use [govendor](https://github.com/kardianos/govendor)

**Edit**

As mkopriva mentions in the comments, you can **refactor import names** using the [`gofmt`](https://golang.org/cmd/gofmt/) tool:

> `gofmt -w -r '"path/to/PackageName" -> "path/to/packagename"' ./`
>
> `gofmt -w -r 'PackageName.x -> packagename.x' ./`

The lowercase single character identifier is a **wildcard**.

from the docs

> The rewrite rule specified with the -r flag must be a string of the form:
>
> `pattern -> replacement`
>
> Both pattern and replacement must be valid Go expressions. In the pattern, single-character lowercase identifiers serve as wildcards matching arbitrary sub-expressions; those expressions will be substituted for the same identifiers in the replacement.

Comment: As an alternative to `grep` one can also use the [gofmt tool](https://golang.org/cmd/gofmt/). E.g. for changing the imports `gofmt -w -r '"path/to/PackageName" -> "path/to/packagename"' ./` and for changing the *selector expressions* on that package `gofmt -w -r 'PackageName.x -> packagename.x' ./`

Answer (score 1):

Just if anyone wonders why this error might occur in your project: Make sure all imports use either lowercase or uppercase path, but not mixed.
So like this:

```
one.go -> "github.com/name/app/login"
another.go -> "github.com/name/app/login"
```

And not like this:

```
one.go -> "github.com/name/app/Login"
another.go -> "github.com/name/app/login"
```